# how to solve duplicate id in sql?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT `timeline_id` , `status_id`
FROM `timeline`,`status`
Where `timeline`.`user_id` = 1
ORDER BY `timeline`.`dates` DESC
```

the output is

```
timeline_id  status_id
1                1
1                2
1                3
2                1
2                2 
2                3
3                1
3                2
3                3
```

Comment: Those aren't duplicates, each of those are different combinations.  Do you want distinct timeline_id, or distinct status_id?  you can't grab both in that query

Comment: They're not duplicates. `select distinct` applies to ALL of the fields you're selecting, not just the first field after the distinct keyword. e.g. it's like `select distinct(a,b,c....)`, not `select distinct(a), b, c, ....`

Answer (score 0):

**If you have field user_id in tbl `status` try this:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT `timeline_id` , `status_id`
FROM `timeline` LEFT JOIN`status`
ON `timeline`.user_id = `status`.user_id
Where `timeline`.`user_id` = 1
ORDER BY `timeline`.`dates` DESC
```